# Am I allowed to take photos of the Umaid Bhawan Palace premises in Jodhpur without being a guest

Tags: india, regulations, photography, jodhpur

Is it possible to take photos of Umaid Bhawan Palace premises if you are not a guest of the hotel? I am mainly interested in taking photos of the back garden with the pavilion and bird-view photos of the lobby.

I tried sending an email to the manager but she didn't respond to it.

[I had this question written and meant to ask it a few weeks ago but forgot. Since I have the answer now, I decided to ask it and answer myself in case anyone needs an answer to the same question.]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the restaurant and bar are open to the public and there are plenty of camera-toting tourists around.  Rather low-quality proof attached:

[image]

But I'd recommend stopping for a meal or drink.  It's not cheap by Indian standards (I vaguely recall paying well north of Rs500 for a curry and a Kingfisher), but it's probably worth it -- it's not every day that you get to visit an actual maharajah's palace, after all.  The outdoor seating in the restaurant has great views of the back garden.